# MS SQL Open XML export to excel from ms sql - C #

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, excel, openxml

Есть следующая выборка:

```
 1. 2017-05-21  13:45:16    Indicator1  15
 2. 2017-05-21  13:45:16    Indicator2  13.8
 3. 2017-05-21  13:45:16    Indicator3 0
 4. 2017-05-21  13:45:16    Indicator4 -7.1
 5. 2017-05-21  13:45:16    Indicator5 0
 6. 2017-05-21  13:45:16    Indicator6 24.2
 7. 2017-05-21  13:45:16    Indicator7 0
 8. 2017-05-21  13:45:16    Indicator8 0
 9. 2017-05-21  13:45:16    Indicator9 0
 10. 2017-05-21 13:45:17    Indicator6 23.2
 11. 2017-05-21 13:45:17    Indicator2  14.1
 12. 2017-05-21 13:45:18    Indicator4  -6.4
 13. 2017-05-21 13:45:18    Indicator6 21.4
 14. 2017-05-21 13:45:19    Indicator6 22
 15. 2017-05-21 13:45:19    Indicator2  14.2
 16. 2017-05-21 13:45:19    Indicator4  -5.9
```

мне нужно экспортировать в excel эти данные и получить в следующем виде:

**Date Time Ind1 Ind2 Ind3 Ind4 Ind5 Ind6 Ind7 Ind8 Ind9**

```
2017-05-21 13:45:16 15 13.8 0 -7.1 0 24.2 0 0 0
2017-05-21 13:45:17 15 14.1 0 -7.1 0 23.2 0 0 0
2017-05-21 13:45:18 15 14.1 0 -6.4 0 21.4 0 0 0
2017-05-21 13:45:19 15 14.2 0 -5.9 0 22 0 0 0
```

```
using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    Row newRow = new Row();
    while (reader.Read())
    {   
        if (reader[1].ToString() != firstTime)
        {
            firstTime = reader[1].ToString();
            newRow.AppendChild(new Cell { DataType = CellValues.String, CellValue = new CellValue(reader[0].ToString()) });
            newRow.AppendChild(new Cell { DataType = CellValues.String, CellValue = new CellValue(firstTime) });
            newRow.AppendChild(new Cell { DataType = CellValues.String, CellValue = new CellValue(reader[3].ToString()) });
        }
        else
        {
            newRow.AppendChild(new Cell { DataType = CellValues.String, CellValue = new CellValue(reader[3].ToString()) });
        }                                            

    }sheetData.Append(newRow);    
}
```

Comment: переведите, пожалуйста, текст вопроса (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса) на русский язык

Answer (score 0):

Вы так и не написали, с чем вам надо разобраться. Возможно, вы хотите менять структуру с помощью Excel, тут я вам не помогу, но мне интересно было решить задачу чистым T-SQL.

Задача тут разбивается на две части:

1. поскольку значение индикатора у вас переносится на следующее
   время, если не задано явно, нужно сначала заполнить пропуски. Делаем
   это с помощью [скрипта от Itzik Ben-Gan](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/last-non-null-puzzle)
2. Получив сплошную выборку, нужно заменить формат вывода, используя PIVOT.

итоговый скрипт получился таким:

```
--Создаем и заполняем тестовые данные
create table #test (Dt datetime, ind nvarchar(10), val decimal(18, 2));
insert into #test
        (Dt, ind, val)
values  ('2017-05-21 13:45:16', 'Indicator1', 15),
        ('2017-05-21 13:45:16', 'Indicator2', 13.8),
        ('2017-05-21 13:45:16', 'Indicator3', 0),
        ('2017-05-21 13:45:16', 'Indicator4', -7.1),
        ('2017-05-21 13:45:16', 'Indicator5', 0),
        ('2017-05-21 13:45:16', 'Indicator6', 24.2),
        ('2017-05-21 13:45:16', 'Indicator7', 0),
        ('2017-05-21 13:45:16', 'Indicator8', 0),
        ('2017-05-21 13:45:16', 'Indicator9', 0),
        ('2017-05-21 13:45:17', 'Indicator6', 23.2),
        ('2017-05-21 13:45:17', 'Indicator2', 14.1),
        ('2017-05-21 13:45:18', 'Indicator4', -6.4),
        ('2017-05-21 13:45:18', 'Indicator6', 21.4),
        ('2017-05-21 13:45:19', 'Indicator6', 22),
        ('2017-05-21 13:45:19', 'Indicator2', 14.2),
        ('2017-05-21 13:45:19', 'Indicator4', -5.9);


with 
--Делаем таблицу пересечения всех возможных значений, присоединяем имеющиеся значения
CreateGaps as 
(
    select  Dates.Dt, Indicators.ind, t.val
    from    (select distinct Dt from #test) as Dates
            cross join (select distinct ind from #test as t) as Indicators
            left  join #test as t
                    on t.Dt = Dates.Dt
                    and t.ind = Indicators.ind
),
--Заменяем null-овые значения на предыдущие
FillGaps as
(
    SELECT Dt, ind,
      CAST(
        SUBSTRING(
          MAX( CAST(Dt AS BINARY(4)) + 
               cast(ind as binary(20)) + 
               cast(val AS BINARY(9)) )
            OVER( partition by Ind order BY Dt
                  ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING ),
          24, 9)
        AS decimal(18, 2)) AS val
    FROM CreateGaps
)
--Разворачиваем таблицу с использованием PIVOT
select Dt, [Indicator1], [Indicator2], [Indicator3]
         , [Indicator4], [Indicator5], [Indicator6]
         , [Indicator7], [Indicator8], [Indicator9]
 from FillGaps as t
 pivot (max(val) for ind in 
          ([Indicator1], [Indicator2], [Indicator3]
          ,[Indicator4], [Indicator5], [Indicator6]
          ,[Indicator7], [Indicator8], [Indicator9])
       ) as pvt;

drop table #test
```